# php preg_match add href .html

Tags: php, regex

I would like to change all href's in a website.

```
<a href="sitename">xyz …</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="sitename.html>xyz …</a>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use a parser. Do not use a regex (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454). As you see in your own question, with the missing closing quote, you don't know what you're going to find in that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the following way ...

```
$hrefs = '<a href="sitename1">xyz …</a>
<a href="sitename2">xyz …</a>';
$r = '/(?<=href=").*?(?=">)/';
$sitename = 'sitename.html';
$result = preg_replace($r, $sitename, $hrefs);
echo $result;
```

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/JUQNNi)**

Answer (score -1):

```
$content = file_get_contents('page.html');

$new_content = str_replace('<a href="', '<a href="sitename.html', $content);

echo $new_content;
```

Comment: All trailing content will still be in the `href`s. Also this assumes all `href`s are encapsulated by double quotes. Best to use a parser.

Comment: Thank you. But, this is not the solution. 'sitename' is variable.

Comment: You could easily add sitename as a variable, $sitename.".html"

Comment: This is not suitable for me.

I just want to change ANY href = "xyz" in href = "xyz.html"

So at each url a ".html" attach.